# Install RealVNC on elementary OS

Tags: software-installation

I wanna install RealVNC on elementary OS!
Unfortunately I can´t find it in the [appcenter](/questions/tagged/appcenter) - how is it possible?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It's not in the appcenter or in synaptic, which is a gui for all the sudo apt-get commands. It is on the realVNC website.

The viewer: https://www.realvnc.com/download/viewer/

The server: https://www.realvnc.com/download/vnc/

Download the .deb files. If you just want a client that connects to a display on another pc then just get the viewer. If you want to screen share into your elementary machine then get the server too.

I'd install these with gdebi. It will look for any software that RealVNC is dependent on and install it as well. You can get gdebi from the appcenter or just run these commands in the terminal after downloading the files:

sudo apt-get install gdebi

cd Downloads

sudo gdebi name_of_realvnc_viewer.deb

sudo gdebi name_of_realvnc_server.deb

That should get it installed. There may be some setup required after install. I haven't used Realvnc in a few years. Switched to nomachine, personal preference and ease of setup, but hopefully thats enough info to get you there.